# Swift converting Eureka date into String for firebase storing

Tags: swift, firebase, eureka-forms

I am attempting to collect the date value from a Eureka DateTimeRow to then store it into Firebase but to store it I would need it to be in a string format. I have attempted this conversion but I receive the error 'Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Date' (0x108af27e8) to 'Swift.String' (0x1086e99f8).'
I would like to know if there is something I am missing from my conversion method.

DateTimeRow:

```
<<< DateTimeRow("startDate"){
            $0.title = "Start Date"
            $0.value = NSDate() as Date
            $0.cellUpdate { (cell, row) in
                cell.datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
            }
                $0.onChange { row in
                    start = row.value!
            }

        }
```

Code getting the values of the Erueka form and converting:

```
let valuesDictionary = form.values()   
let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                let formattedDate = formatter.date(from: valuesDictionary["startDate"] as! String)
```

Thank you all feedback welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to convert *from* a `Date` (Eureka) *to* a `String` (Firebase), you should use the [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415810-string) method of the `DateFormatter`, whereas you are attempting to use the [`date(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1409994-date) method.

> ```
> // Date to String
> func string(from date: Date) -> String
>
> // String to Date
> func date(from string: String) -> Date?
> ```